# Critical Dice Damage Removal alternatives

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, paladin, critical-hit

First-time poster, I actually have a multipart question.

So, our DM got upset when my Paladin crit with my smite ability while having a hunter's mark on this Werewolf encounter. So in the end it was as so.

2d8 Slashing (Longsword)
2d6 Hunter's Mark
6d8 Radiant Damage (level 2 spell used up for smite)
+4 Strength Modifier

So he argued that critical strikes won't work that way and since I struck with a melee weapon it is the melee attack that crits, not my smite. I did show him the comment from Crawford and argued the smite is not so much a spell as linked to my sword strike and arguably can at least be a hybrid attack and should choose which dice roll to double at least.

In the end, it is deemed that critical strikes do not double all damage dice because he feels it is too encounter breaking. So pretty much, even though a Paladin is still great with smites, it really takes away a holding smite factor for that one bomb strike.

End result:
2d8 melee
1d6 Hunters
3d8 Radiant
+4

So far less spectacular for rolling that nat 20.

I believe he also has it in his mind since I am the party tank, I guess I should not be capable of such massive strikes. Despite the damage output of our resident rogue and Warlock.

**So with that explanation out, here are my questions!**

*What abilities or spells can help maintain more consistent damage output with the lose of saving my smites for criticals now?*

Or

*What are good class alternatives that can soak damage and return the damage to the table that would perform better than a nerfed Paladin?*

Opinions?

Comment: Sorry, 5th Edition.

Comment: I would ask one or the other question. The answer for keeping up with the party is too vague and needs to be made specific with regards to what you are trying to keep up with on. The alternatives has a very different answer.

Comment: Well, before I would save my smites for either dire moments or critical "Holy smokes" moments and other such. I have doubled my smites before but he stated he didn't know I was doing that. Anyways, normally I am just walking around doing 1d8+4 damage per strike while our ranger, rogue, warlocks are dishing out more than that easy and often taunt the Paladin for "Not keeping up" or "pulling his weight" even though I am the front line soaking damage.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Comment: The main reason I believe this question is unanswerable is because what you *were* doing is RAW, but your DM has chosen to disallow it. Nothing we suggest is DM-proof. That is, it may be just 100% RAW and achieve your goal, meaning your DM could just as easily choose not to allow it because he's unhappy with it.

Comment: Frankly if a DM were to gut a class defining RAW feature like this I would be reluctant to role ANY other character for fear of him doing the same again, at least if 'power' is part of your goal.

Comment: You might want to show your DM [this article](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/modifying-classes) from one of the 5e designers which _specifically_ identifies the ability of paladins to combo Divine Smite with critical hits as a key class feature.